# How to build statistics on a procedures execution in oracle 12.2?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, oracle12c

I have a ~2,300 line package, which is split into many procedures & function. It is running slower than I would like. Many years ago on a previous release of Oracle (9i or 11g) I had a similar problem and I was able to build a hierarchical structure which contained everything that was executed in the procedure/package an how much time was spent on each item.

I cannot seem to find a tutorial/blog that shows how to accomplish this. It is probably done with the DBMS_STATS package, but  I find Oracle's documentation unsuitable for task oriented problem solving. It may be great if you want to learn everything there is to know about a subject, but generally all I need to know is how to solve the issue I am currently working on.

At any rate can someone point me to how I can get the runtime statistics of a run of an Oracle Procedure?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, if you post that as an answer, and include the link https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/plsql-hierarchical-profiler-11gr1 I will certainly upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. dbms_profiler - records times on each statement executed. [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_profil.htm#ARPLS039)
2. dbms_hpof - similar, but collects statistics on a hierarchy of pl/sql calls [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm#CHDBHDFE)

Either method will require some setup using SYS (dba) access.  [Setup Instuctions for dbms_profiler](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_profiler)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried dbms_utility.get_time method as described in [THIS](https://qr.ae/pNrr5h) post.

Link to the original question which is almost the same as your question.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-log-the-execution-time-of-a-stored-procedures-in-a-table-in-Oracle-database

Comment: That is not a good approach as you have to insert calls in your code. DBMS_PROFILER does all that without any additional instrumentation needed.

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks for the heads up. I did not know about DBMS_PROFILER.

Comment: What @Oldprogrammer said. It would require much modification to the procedures and functions to add the code.